# Using FBFriendPickerViewController with Parse framework

Tags: ios, facebook, friend, picker, parse-framework

I'm trying to build a facebook friend selector. At the moment I'm using the Parse framework for logging into my app using my Fb account. Do you know if it's possible to use the FacebookSDK's FBFriendPickerViewController once logged using Parse? I've given a try using https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/add-search-to-friend-picker-using-ios-sdk/ but the view controller doesn't load any data.

Should I create a friend selector from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this helps but you can use PF_FBFriendPickerViewController with parse. It works exactly like is described in the FB iOS SDK.